Getting error while recalling a value input by the user using a textbox in tkinter
import mysql.connector as sqlTor
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import random

class PositionFinder:
    #--------------------Constructor-------------------#
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.title("Flair")
        self.root.geometry("1340x730")
        lbltitle = Label(self.root,
                   bd=20,
                   relief=RIDGE,
                   text="FLAIR",
                   fg="red",
                   bg="white",
                   font=("times new roman",50,"bold")
                            )
        lbltitle.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
    #----------------------Data Frame------------------#
        Dataframe=LabelFrame(self.root,
                             bd=20,
                             relief=RIDGE,
                             padx=10,
                             font=("times new roman",12,"bold"),
                             text="Player Details",
                             fg="red")
        
        Dataframe.place(x=0,y=130,width=1340,height=600)

    #----------------Data Frame Elements---------------#

        #Name
        name=StringVar() 
        lblname=Label(Dataframe,font=("arial",12,"bold"),text="Name",padx=2)
        lblname.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
        textname=Entry(Dataframe,textvariable=name,font=                ("arial",13,"bold"),width=35)
        textname.grid(row=0,column=1)

        #Age
        age=IntVar()
        lblage=Label(Dataframe,font=("arial",12,"bold"),text="Age",padx=2,pady=20)
        lblage.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
        textage=Entry(Dataframe,textvariable=age,font=("arial",13,"bold"),width=35)
        textage.grid(row=1,column=1)

        

        #SaveButton
        button1=Button(Dataframe,command=EventHandler,text='Save',fg="red",font= ("arial",12,"bold"))
        button1.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)

def EventHandler():
    na=name.get()
    print(na)
            
root=Tk()
ob=PositionFinder(root)
root.mainloop()

I started learning about tkinter today for a project so please help me with any other mistakes i may have
After Inputing name and age and clicking save i go this error
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1968, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\abhin\Downloads\Comp Project\main.py", line 65, in EventHandler
    na=name.get()
       ^^^^
NameError: name 'name' is not defined


name is a local variable in __init__(). You can't access it in EventHandler(). Make it a global variable. Or make it an instance variable, and move EventHandler() into the class.
